# How to add border color and width to ion-avatar

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have no success trying to add a border color and width to an ion-avatar element in ionic4, I've trying to collocate some css3 code but with no success.

I have tested with this but it does not work:

```
  .ion-avatar img{
      width: 90px !important;
      height: 60px !important;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;

      border: 70px solid red !important;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure nested relationship is ` .ion-avatar img` ?

Answer (score 4):

works fine if you just referrer to the element `ion-avatar` as opposed to the class `.ion-avatar`

```
 ion-avatar img{
      width: 90px !important;
      height: 60px !important;
      border-radius: 50% !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;

      border: 70px solid red !important;
    }
```

[image]